# Only my first PHP tag is being used

Tags: php, html

Basically, only my first php tag is actually being used by the browser. Everything was working normally, then for some reason everything except my header disappeared. It's the same for every page on the site as well.

This is my index file, for example:

```
<?php require_once('includes/header.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('includes/footer.php'); ?>
```

The only being displayed by the user is the header. If I comment out the require for the header, then the footer is displayed, but not the header...

Here is my header file:

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE = html>
<html lang="en-us">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>7four</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <?php

    if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        require_once('includes/logged_nav.php');
    } else {
        require_once('includes/nav.php');
    }

    ?>

<?php require_once('functions.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('db.php'); ?>
```

How on earth do I resolve this problem? Sorry if I'm being dense!

Comment: That is super weird, and should not be happening. I use a similar setup and it works just fine. Just BTW you can take the "=" out of the doctype.

Comment: I know right! So strange, and it's not even like I can output any errors. I have no idea where there's an '=' sign there... type I presume.

Comment: Turn on error reporting at the top of your script with `<?php ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1);` and debug. Update your question with any errors that may pop up.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is displayed? Or nothing shows up in the "View Source" section.

Remove the `=` from `< ! DOCTYPE = html >` , and try again.

Comment: guaranteed that wont be it!

Answer (score 0):

Remove `<?php ob_start(); ?>` on header file. If you want use ob_start(); you need 
set

```
$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

And put `print $output;` on index file.

See more doc about [ob_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)

Answer (score 0):

You have an error somewhere, probably in functions.php or db.php. Your error reporting is turned off and your footer is not displayed here:

```
<?php require_once('includes/header.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('includes/footer.php'); ?>
```

The footer is displayed correctly here:

```
<?php require_once('includes/footer.php'); ?>
```

Conclusion:
You need to find the error if you look into the logs on the server, or turn on error reporting. If your site is online, then I recommend looking into the logs and to avoid displaying the errors to the users. Find the error and fix it. After that the footer will be displayed as well. Focus on the last changes you did just before this problem started to occur.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so, the issue was fixed by requiring my functions.php file in the nav.php. I then realised that I required my functions.php file underneath where the nav is meant to be displayed, so the nav didn't have proper access to functions.php. Basically I made a silly mistake. Sorry for wasting all of your time!